# How to get ShellExecute to work with pathname longer then 57 chars?

Tags: delphi

Am trying to launch quake from its directory using code below but the pathname is more then 50+ chars so its not working due to limits is there anyway to do larger pathnames?

Pathname example

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Gaming\Toys\Q2\quake2.exe

```
procedure TAutoLauncher.OKBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  parameters : string;
  toydir : string;
begin
  if FileFound then
  begin
    ToyDir := ExtractFilePath(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)) + 'Toys\';
    FolderNameEdit.Text := ToyDir + 'Q2\quake2.exe';
    //
    parameters := Trim('');
    case ModeBox.ItemIndex of
      0: parameters := ' +connect '+ HostEdit.Text +':'+ PortEdit.Text +' +password '+ PasswordEdit.Text;
      1: parameters := ' +set game ctf';
      2: parameters := ' +set game rogue';
      3: parameters := ' +set game xatrix';
    end;
    //
    ShellExecute(handle, 'open', PChar(FolderNameEdit.Text), PChar(parameters), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
   end else
   begin
     Application.MessageBox('Quake2 files not found.', 'Game Not Found', MB_OK OR MB_ICONQUESTION);
  end;
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: What specific problem are you having? What gives you the idea it's because of a path limitation? And what Delphi version are you using?

Comment: And why are you not checking the return value of ShellExecute to see why it's failing (presuming it is in fact failing)?

Comment: There is a path length limit for ShellExecute, but that limit is 2048 (or 260 in the unlikely event that you are still running on Windows 95).  i.e. a path length of 57 is absolutely *not* your problem here.

Comment: There is also a basic flaw in the logic.  It seems to be already decided that the file has been located (*FileFound = TRUE*) but *after* this a path to the file is derived.  If that path wasn't previously known or was derived differently then the **FileFound** indicator doesn't seem to be reliable at this point.  I would add a **FileExists()** check on the **actual** filename you think you are about to `open`.  As Ken suggests, you cannot simply assume that the only reason *ShellExecute()* could fail is because the file doesn't exist.  Identify and report the *real* error and act on that.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `ShellExecute()` to launch an `.exe` file anyway. You should be using `CreateProcess()` instead.

Comment: delphi xe2 and problem is when launching game out side of its own directory it will not load it gives error on quake missing file due to file path being to long

Comment: Then that's an issue with Quake. ShellExecute does not contain such a limitation. As this issue is with Quake, it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShellExecute does not contain such a limitation; [the limit is the INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH (around 2048) unless you're running on windows 95 (in which case it's MAX_PATH)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553), according to Raymond Chen of Microsoft.

Here's a sample XE8 application compiled as a 32-bit app and run on Windows 10 to demonstrate. (And, even though ShellExecute is the wrong way to launch an executable as Remy said, it also shows you the correct way to use it and test the return value for errors.)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  ShellAPI;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FilePath: string;
  Res: Integer;
begin
  FilePath := 'C:\Users\Ken\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Seattle\Android\AndroidBase\Debug\Styles.xml';

  // This works, using the long (96 character) string as the parameters
  Res := ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'notepad.exe', PChar(FilePath), nil, SW_NORMAL);
  if Res < 32 then
    RaiseLastOSError(GetLastError);

  // This works, using the long (96 character) string as the filename
  Res := ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(FilePath), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
  if Res < 32 then
    RaiseLastOSError(GetLastError);

end;

end.
```

It appears from your comments above that it is Quake itself that is generating the error. In that case, the issue is not a programming issue, but something you should address with the software vendor.

Comment: No idea it works fine when application is in the same folder as the exe but soon as i move it out side of the folder it says missing file maybe parameters field is effecting it mmm

Comment: Ok I fixed it thanks very much for the help people have a good night 2am here bed for me

Comment: @SimonWpgnLewis You say that it works when your application is in the same folder than quake but not other vise That is due the fact that when you are using ShellExecute to start another application that application working folder is set to the same working folder of your own application. That would be the same as if you would try to start quake with a shortcut that has no working directory parameter defined I which case quake would have set working directory to the location of the shortcut itself. ....

Comment: ... That is why you should be using CreateProcess instead as it allows you to set working directory for started application to custom location of your own choosing.

Comment: @Silver So does ShellExecute

Comment: `the limit is 2K characters` - but only with specially crafted `\\.\...` path. Traditional 'C:\...` path still to be limited by `MAX_PATH` - 260 chars

Comment: @Arioch'The: See the link I just added.

Comment: @KenWhite good one, thanks. But it discusses "command line length limit" and none, one or many file paths are subparts of the command line. Whether ShellExecute would manage to interpret longer paths within that long command string is to be tested. For example you can take Windows Explorer, put it to the edge of MAX_PATH and try to enter subfolder. 2000/XP explorer would fail AFAIR. Vista+ Explorer would convert path to 8.3 names compressing it and would enter the subfolder. A little workaround was added.... Indeed, ShellExecute may have similar tricks to manage long paths in some versions....

Comment: @Arioch'The: Not true. The last section discusses specifically the max parameter length for ShellExecute/Ex: *If you are using the ShellExecute/Ex function, then you become subject to the INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH (around 2048) command line length limit imposed by the ShellExecute/Ex functions. (If you are running on Windows 95, then the limit is only MAX_PATH.)*

Comment: @KenWhite just read what you quoted - *INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH (around 2048) **command line length** limit imposed by the ShellExecute/Ex functions* - Sadly Chen is not very clear here which of many PChar parameters of ShellExecute he discusses. But I think the safe assumption would be he only told about Command Line parameter of ShellExecute. We might *guess* he also meant all others parameters too, but personally if I would ever rely on it - then only after my own testing in all supported Windows versions, especially older ones

Comment: @Arioch'The: I would presume that it would mean the combined length of the filename + parameters can be up to 2048 characters, since it refers to *command line length*, and if you typed it at the *command line*, it would be *<filename> <parameters>*.

Comment: @KenWhite `cmd.exe /c copy file1+file2+file3 file123` - we have a single cmd line with 4 (four) filepaths in it. It is rather common thing, if not the most frequent. Same for tar/pkzip/7z/rar and other archivers.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Yes. You have an executable (cmd.exe) followed by multiple values that make up the **parameters**. Those combined constitute the **command line** and cannot add up to more than 2048 characters. I don't know why you're finding this difficult to understand. Let me try this: **Whatever you type between `C:\>` and the time you hit ENTER is the command line, and the total of those characters cannot exceed 2048 characters.**.

Comment: @KenWhite Perfect, Ken. You almost got it now! Now there is documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx - and it shoes that in context for THIS question the command line starts with the space after "cmd.exe", so `you type between C:\> and the time you hit ENTER` is a slightly off, actually *whatever you type **after the program file name** and before hitting ENTER` is the command line* but other than that you got it now.

Comment: Now I believe you are ready to make the next step and understand that *the command line* only limits *the allowed path name* from above but not from below! - there is nothing we can tell about the X `x<=Length(FilePath) <= Length(CommandLine) <= 2048`. There is no substantiation to tell "FilePath is always allowed to be as long as any command line", especially so when those are DIFFERENT ARGUMENTS of the function. You claim that since `lpParameters` is allowed to be up to 2048 chars long it necessary means `lpFile` is also allowed to be 2048-long. That your claim is not substantiated by URLs

Comment: @Arioch'The: I claim no such thing. Do me a favor and go argue with Raymond Chen - it's his blog post you're insisting on arguing about with me.

Comment: I have no disagreements with mr. Chen - he says nothing about file path length - so we have nothing to argue. On the contrary, you do claim that max file path length is 2048 and you base it upon mr. Chen saying nothing about it

Comment: @Arioch'The: No. I quoted precisely what Raymond said (I even linked the entire quote), so if you disagree with what I quoted discuss it with Raymond. He wrote it. It's on his blog pages. I said absolutely no such thing; every word in my answer related to the max length are from Raymond. Stop trolling me.